# Toggle switcher explanation. Use or don't?

Tags: toggle

Is it necessary to use toggle explanation? In my case toggle have 2 options: YES or NO. Which one would you use and why?
[image: Toggle switcher]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A toggle having colour indicates that it is switched "on" - in this case, that means YES. You shouldn't need any further information.

The tick/cross icons can add a fun little bit of flavour to the toggles, but I believe that explanations for toggles generally aren't necessary - the [Material guidelines for switches](https://material.io/design/components/selection-controls.html#switches) agrees with that idea.

Comment: For accessibility, shouldn't we consider users with colorblindness? Or users with monochrome devices? (Admittedly, the latter is exceptionally rare in most cases, but it could depend on the expected demographic.) In those cases, color alone isn't enough to differentiate.

Comment: That's certainly something to consider, yes; in that instance, I believe the tick/cross icons would work as suitable visual feedback without cluttering the layout.

Answer (score 1):

The examples the "off" switches do not have enough contrast against the background. They look to me as if the option was not only "off" but "disabled" as well.

And I would go with the plain switch or the v/x option.

Answer (score 0):

I find Jonny S answer to be the best solution for this question. The reason I would choose the color toggle option is because this will clearly indicate that the option selected is turned on, and when you switch back it turns grey for off.

Hope these answers helps you with your UX processes.